# ng-click does not work in ionic header button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a button on the right side of the header bar, the button is showing, but ng-click does not get fired, if I move the button inside ion-content, it starts working, just not working in header.

html :

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7" >
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Trips</h1>
        <div class="buttons pull-right"><button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus" ng-click="createTrip()"></button></div>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

js:

```
.controller('TripCtrl', function($scope, $location, $localStorage){
    console.log('inside TripCtrl');

    $scope.$storage = $localStorage;

    var random1 = {
        name : 'random name 1',
        text : 'random text 1'
    }

    var random2 = {
        name : 'random name 2',
        text : 'random text 2'
    }

    $scope.trips = [];
    $scope.trips.push(random1);
    $scope.trips.push(random2);


    $scope.createTrip = function(){
        console.log('clicked create new');
        $location.path('/createTrip');
    }
})
```

Comment: need more code, what controller is managing that button click? It is not clear from the code you provided

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure `createTrip` is defined inside app's root controller and also note ion-header-bar doesn't listen for click event by default. if you want to bind click event inside ion-header-bar you must have to wrap the target element inside button block of ion-header-bar.

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/

Answer (score -1):

I did something similar, however i'm using `ui-sref` to go directly to my partial. My guess is you need to  add that controller to your header, that way it will fire at any screen you are (just like the back button).